# Application icon hide not working on Some Devices

Tags: android

i want hide my icon from launcher,its working on below 20 sdk but not working not above 21 sdk, my code is below for hide icon :

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Code for Visible Icon

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from AndroidManifest by removing this line

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

Comment: when i remove it, i'm not able to run